# cv2.VideoCapture: Why is .read() always returns false but .open() is always True?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

`cap.read()` is not working. `ret` is always false but `cap.isOpened()` is true.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print(cap.isOpened())
ret , img = cap.read()
print(ret)
cv2.imshow(" ", img)
cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It gives the following error,

> error: OpenCV(3.4.1)
>   C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1533128839831\work\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:356:
>   error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: if you believe this is the problem with CV2 Video capture, I'd recommend raising an issue on package's Github

Comment: how many camera is connected to the machine? you got that error because the img is empty. You can verify this by printing np.shape(img)